# Retrieve data from Firebase using REST API

Tags: android, firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read all the following data from firebase using Retrofit. I don't want to use Firebase SDK! I have saved data to Firebase in the following format:

```
"xyz@gmail,com": {
    "d1d1b69c-71c9-492a-b4ac-3afaceed0584": {
      "videos": {
         "currentUserEmail":"xyz@gmail.com",
         "dateUploaded":"Aug 26, 2019, 07:15",
         "description":"",
         "id":"d1d1b69c-71c9-492a-b4ac-3afaceed0584",
         "title":"test1",
         "userImage":"",
         "username":"xyz",
         "videoPath":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/aVideoPath..."
   }
},

    "e510e59c-9959-4931-8070-e00ea0e64768": {
       "videos": {
          "currentUserEmail":"some@some.com",
          "dateUploaded":"Aug 26, 2019, 07:16",
          "description":"",
          "id":"e510e59c-9959-4931-8070-e00ea0e64768",
          "title":"test2",
          "userImage":"",
          "username":"someUser",
          "videoPath":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/aVideoPath..."
    }
  }
}
```

I am having trouble creating POJO from this json data, partly because of the Unique Id. I tried using jsonschema2pojo to generate POJO but as you can guess, the POJO looks something like this:

```
    XyzGmailCom {
     @SerializedName("d1d1b69c-71c9-492a-b4ac-3afaceed0584"
     private d1d1b69c-71c9-492a-b4ac-3afaceed0584 d1d1b69c-71c9-492a-b4ac-3afaceed0584;
}
```

Probably I am not using proper logic to save data correctly. Can somebody please guide me on how to save and read such data from firebase using retrofit? Would really appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think retrofit can do it because Firebase doesn't use RESTful API, maybe even they don't use json format inside.

Comment: Which Firebase database are you using, Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore?  Why don't you want to use the provided SDKs?

Comment: @Doug Stevenson I am using the Realtime Database. I am using the Retrfoit because the response is bit faster than provided SDK,

Comment: @Spark.Bao I am already using Retrofit to save and read data in some other scenarios. However, I got stuck in reading the list of videos that I am saving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after all sorts of try and error, I came up with a workaround solution. I am using JsonDeserializer to deserialize the json object and then looping through the object to get the keys, once I am inside the nested object, I am re-creating the UsersVideoRes from the json object and returning the object. The code is given below:

```
public class UserVideosAdapterFactory implements JsonDeserializer<UsersVideoRes> {
    private final List<UsersVideo> usersVideoList = new ArrayList<>();
    private UsersVideoRes usersVideoRes = new UsersVideoRes();
    @Override
    public UsersVideoRes deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        Set<String> keys = jsonObject.keySet();
        for (String key : keys) {
            JsonElement jsonElement = jsonObject.get(key);
            JsonObject jsonObject1 = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
            Set<String> key1 = jsonObject1.keySet();
            for (String videoKey : key1) {
                UsersVideo usersVideo = new UsersVideo();
                JsonElement videoElement = jsonObject1.get(videoKey);
                JsonObject videoObject = videoElement.getAsJsonObject();
                String id = videoObject.get("id").getAsString();
                String videoPath = videoObject.get("videoPath").getAsString();
                String userImage = videoObject.get("userImage").getAsString();
                String currentUserEmail = videoObject.get("currentUserEmail").getAsString();
                String dateUploaded = videoObject.get("dateUploaded").getAsString();
                String description = videoObject.get("description").getAsString();
                String title = videoObject.get("title").getAsString();
                String username = videoObject.get("username").getAsString();
                usersVideo.setId(id);
                usersVideo.setVideoPath(videoPath);
                usersVideo.setUserImage(userImage);
                usersVideo.setCurrentUserEmail(currentUserEmail);
                usersVideo.setDateUploaded(dateUploaded);
                usersVideo.setDescription(description);
                usersVideo.setTitle(title);
                usersVideo.setUsername(username);
                this.usersVideoList.add(usersVideo);
                usersVideoRes.setUsersVideoList(this.usersVideoList);
            }
        }
        return this.usersVideoRes;
    }
```

It works as I expected, however, I personally don't think it's a good solution, there might be better way, so still hoping someone will come up with better solution for this problem thanks again.